# ASP.NET Core: FileNotFound Error when adding Scaffolded Item

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, asp.net-core, model-view-controller, razor-pages

I tried adding a scaffolded item (Razor page using Entity Framework (CRUD)) under my Models folder following the [MSDN tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/razor-pages/model?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio) and received the following issue:

[image]

It specifies the file name but I'm not sure where to find the directory/folder. And even if I find the folder, I'm not sure what to do next.

Comment: try to update your ms framework to latest version

Comment: @vahab-balouchzahi I think it's the NuGet package [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Utils/) but VS is currently being repaired so I have to wait to find out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As in my response, the answer lies in the fact that it is actually the NuGet package found here:

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Utils/

Right-clicking the projects, browsing for the NuGet package solves the issue.